# developing against container - changing owner of ./git objects for an externally mounted volume

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code, docker-compose, vscode-devcontainer

i have the following in my container that i am developing in.  The code im working on is a volume at /workspaces. the purpose of this code is to change  ownership of all objects/files just before i change user and run as myself...

```
ARG USER
ARG USER_ID
ARG GROUP_ID

RUN if id $USER &>/dev/null; then userdel -f $USER; fi
RUN useradd -l -u ${USER_ID} -g ${GROUP_ID}  $USER 
RUN mkdir /workspaces
RUN chown -R $USER /workspaces
```

In Docker compose, i change user with:

```
    args:
       USER: ${USER}
```

The problem i see though is that under workspaces/.git/objects, there are a number of files that still have owner set to root.
The problem here i think is that the volume is only mounted after the container is started. so the chown command above does not affect the files that existed or were created before.
So when i try to do a git command that may try to modify those files, i get a permission error.

How do i ownership of all files after the volume is mounted?  **Im using docker-compose to build the container.**

EDIT:
@lemoana. to mount the volume, i have this:

```
    volumes:
      - ../..:/workspaces:cached
```

@DavidMaze: running the ide/debugging on the host is problematic because of very inconsistent environments and dependencies on the host and limited permission to 'fix' this or install additional tools libraries.
and yes, right now what i had to do is do a one time chown of all workspaces related files to the user.  this is still problematic for other dependent containers that im spinning up from images that are required for the infrastructure, such as mongodb, redis etc...they still are created as root and so i can easily wipe/cleanup their files from host without doing what you say.
would be nice if that could be done as a post hook and as root  using docker compose before it changes to the running user.

Comment: what do you do to mount the your volume into */workspaces* in your container using docker-compose?

Comment: The volume mount hides everything the image sets up in this directory here, including its ownership and permissions.  You need to run `sudo chown ...` on the host system to fix the ownership.  You might consider running your IDE, source control, debugger, _etc._ directly on the host to avoid this complexity.